# how to convert chinese string to byte array and byte array to chinese string?

Tags: java, android

I am programming converting chinese string to byte array and byte array to chinese string.
I know when using UTF-8 encode, chinese string return 2 bytes.
But It returns 3 bytes in my computer.

```
//test code

String result = System.getProperty("file.encoding"); // UTF-8

String temp = new String("中国");

byte[] bytes = temp.getBytes();
```

Result:

bytes = {-28,-72,-83,-27,-101,-67}

But I don'k know well.
Please help me. Thanks

Comment: `I know when using UTF-8 encode, chinese string return 2 bytes` source?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you're getting the assertion that Chinese characters are all 2 bytes in UTF-8.

中 is U+4E2D, and 国 is U+56FD. If you look at the summary of [how many bytes each code point takes in UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), you'll see that code points between U+0800 and U+FFFF (inclusive) require 3 bytes. Both of the characters here fall in that range.

For instance, 中 (U+4E2D) encodes as 11100100 10111000 10101101 (you can play with UTF8-to-binary conversions [here](https://sites.google.com/site/nathanlexwww/tools/utf8-convert)), and those three bytes do in fact translate to -28, -72 and -83 in twos complement (you can play with decimal-to-two's complement [here](http://www.exploringbinary.com/twos-complement-converter/)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. you help me